# calling function from shared library in c

Tags: c, shared-libraries

I have a file named shared.c as which i suppose to create a libddl.so shared object such that I can call from another c file.

```
#include "second.c"

int a(int b)
{
    display();
  return b+1;
}

int c(int d)
{
  return a(d)+1;
}
```

here i have display() function which I want to call from shared library and defined in second.c as

```
#include <stdio.h>

 void display()
{

    printf("we are here");
}
```

finally I have call.c file which calls the shared library as

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <iostream>

 using namespace std;

typedef int (*pointer)(int b);
//int (*c)(int d);

int main()
{
    int b,d;
    void *lib;
 pointer calc;
  lib=dlopen("libddl.so",RTLD_LAZY);
   if (!lib)
 {
   cerr << "Cannot open library: " << dlerror() << '\n';
        return 1;
 }


  calc= (pointer) dlsym(lib,"a");
  b= calc(2);
  calc= (pointer) dlsym(lib,"c");
  d= calc(2);

  dlclose(lib);


  cout<<"b="<<b<<"and"<<"d="<<d;
  return 0;
}
```

Is it possible to call a function from shared library which defination is in another file.????

command to create the shared library gives following error[image]

Comment: Do you include a `.c` file? Doing so is not considered best practice.

Comment: I have tried it and it works. I do agree though, it is more elegant to compile `second.c` into `second.o` and link them both

Comment: @Davidvanrijn do u mean that the above program is running well without generating error?

Comment: Yes, it compiled, and gave the expected output